# OpenGL: Triangles with points at infinity

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to render a two-dimensional half-plane in OpenGL with the following code:

```
void renderHalfplane(double *x, double *n)
{
  glPushMatrix();
  double theta = -360.0 * atan2(n[0], n[1])/(2.0*PI);

  glTranslated(x[0], x[1], 0);
  glRotated(theta, 0, 0, 1.0);

  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex4d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glVertex4d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex4d(0.0,-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex4d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1,0);
  glVertex4d(-1.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex4d(0.0,-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glEnd();

  glPopMatrix();
}
```

Here I'm using homogeneous coordinates to draw triangles with two vertices at "infinity."

This code works like a charm on my computer, but a user is reporting that it doesn't render correctly on theirs: instead of an infinite half-plane they are seeing two (finite) triangles.

Is my use of w-coordinate 0 undefined behavior? Is it something that only works on some versions of OpenGL? I tried looking through the Khronos OpenGL specs but couldn't find a section where rendering of primitives with w-coordinate 0 was addressed.

Comment: what's the device of your user ?

Comment: According to the user he is using a laptop running Ubuntu with Mesa OpenGL drivers. I have a desktop with Ubuntu but it render fine when I test the code there.

Comment: It is very odd to use w = 0... you should test it on different graphic card drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on my machine(nVidia Quadro) and it renders correctly.  I've found code samples (for shadow volumes) that scales the W coordinate to infinity that work fine also.

I'm going to guess it's a driver issue or something external to this code?

Comment: Any word on what the issue was? Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Curious also ... I use this technique and want to know whether it's unreliable.

Comment: No, I never did get it to work, so I changed the way I did the rendering. From what I've read the snippet *should* be correct, and my guess is that the Mesa drivers in question were old/non-compliant/buggy.